# En changeant le moins de mots que possible, comment actualiser "cestui a que use le feoffment fuit fait" en 2021 moderne français?

Tags: ancien-français, droit-et-justice

> <sup>13</sup> 13 Short for *cestui a que use le feoffment fuit fait* ('he to whose use the feoffment was made'). The
> word 'use' here has no connection with 'to use' but derives from *opus* via the Old French *oeps, oes*.
> Yet the Latin *usus* had the same meaning and is found in later English conveyances in the doublet
> *opus et usus* ('use and behoof).

John Baker, *Introduction to English Legal History* 2019 5 edn, [Connais-tu quel numéro de page?](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_to_English_Legal_History/bPqNDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cestui+a+que+use+le+feoffment+fuit+fait%22&pg=PT422&printsec=frontcover)

Je suis  irréfragable  que ces mots peuvent rester inchangés : [le féoffment](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/manuscriptsandspecialcollections/researchguidance/deedsindepth/freehold/feoffment.aspx). *Fait* est le participe passé de *faire*.

Il faut réviser *use* à [*ad opus*](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195369380.001.0001/acref-9780195369380-e-128).

> 1.24 The term ‘use’ is somewhat misleading. It is a corruption of the Latin *ad opus*. What it means
> is ‘on behalf of ’ or ‘for the benefit of ’, so to grant land ‘to the use’ of someone meant that the
> feoffees to use were not entitled to treat the land as their own, but must hold it on behalf of or
> for the benefit of the cestui(s) que use. A typical example of an enfeoffment to uses will give
> something of the flavour of a medieval use.

J.E. Penner, J. Lau, *Law of Trusts* 2019 11 edn, p 10.

**Mais comment  paraphraser tous les autres mots ?**

1. Comment actualiser *cestui*? Ceci est devenu *celui*?
2. a = à?
3. que = qui ou que en 2021?
4. *fuit* = Le passé simple d'*être* actuel = *fut*? Etait *fuit* une version   désuete de *fut*?

Comment: Cestui used to mean this one while celui was that one. This distinction collapsed in middle French, with the cest- demonstratives becoming the basis of the determiners (cet, cette) and the cel- demonstratives that of the pronouns (celui, celle, ceux)

Answer (score 1):

[Cestui](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cestui) → *Celui*
a → *à* (Il n'y avait pas d'accents en ancien français)
que → *qui* (dans ce cas)
fuit → Passé simple de *être*. Il me semble l'avoir déjà vu sans  *t* final, mais il n'y avait pas d’orthographe fixée à cette époque.

L'expression est traduite ainsi dans [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_French) « celui à l'usage duquel l'inféodation fut faite [à qui le fief fut donné] ». Et [cette page](https://stringfixer.com/fr/Law_French) donne cette traduction : « celui pour qui le feoffment a été fait » ce qui me semble correct aussi, sauf qu'absolument personne ne comprend le mot *feoffment* de nos jours. [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/fieffement) donne cette traduction de *feoffment* : « terre constituée en fief ». « Inféodation » donné dans wikipedia est peu employé en dehors des spécialistes mais peut encore être trouvé dans les dictionnaires.

Comment: À should become *pour* really: celui pour qui ce fiefment a été fait

Comment: Celui pour l'usage duquel la création en fief a été faite, even

Comment: @Eauquidort   C'est le cas de la traduction reproduite du dictionnaire de  Robert Kelham que je signale.  J'ai donné deux traductions différentes existantes, parce que je ne suis pas assez compétente pour faire la mienne. Tu penses que *pour l'usage duquel* est mieux que *à l'usage duquel* ?  Je ne sens pas la différence, mais elle peut exister ! Le fuit avec un t m'étonne mais toi qui connaît bien l'ancien français tu devrais faire une réponse !

Comment: Ma référence donne "fu, fut ; fud ; fuit ; fust ; fuy ; feu" comme variantes attestées de fut en AF. Ca ne m'étonne pas trop, la diphtongue ui est probablement empruntée à la première personne (je fuy), qui elle même est empruntée à des formes comme je suy, je sçay, je vay, etc. Mais ils auraient assez naturellement rajouté un t à la troisième personne, comme pour ces autres verbes.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de la préposition, c'est juste mon feeling pour le français moderne, "ce titre a été créé à l'usage de X" me semble moins naturel que "ce titre a été créé pour l'usage de X"